# Translucent NavigationBar behaves strange when calling

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a `UINavigationController` in which I define the `navigationBar` for all `UIViewControllers` as follows:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

I do this because there are some views,

**for example**: the profile view of a user, which needs to be transparant in order to show a `backgroundImage` behind the username and profile picture.

This of course means the height of the `navigationBar` becomes zero, so I need to set all my views accordingly and do this by pinning my topAnchors to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`.

I continue by calculating the height of the `navigationBar`. My code to get the height is:

```
navBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!
```

This works like a charm. I can then create a custom UIView with the height set to the `navBarHeight`, adding the color I want on my regular views and it works just fine.

However, it doesn't work when something comes up in the *status bar*.

**For example**: when I am calling, or when my personal homespot has active connection, when I am recording (voice or screen), a red, green or blue overlay is visible in the statusBar and the height increases. If I then open my app, the height is not right and the height of the `navigationBar` view is too high, making my main content partly invisible on top.

How can I take this into account?

Comment: If it was navegationBar `isTranslucent = true` the y equal zero will be from the beginning of the View, But `isTranslucent = false`  the y equal zero started from below navegationbar

Comment: Translucency is set to true for all ViewControllers. So the y-value always starts from the beginning of the view, but this doesn't really help me as I need to change the navBarHeight variable in my OP I guess?

Answer (score 1):

I have now fixed this by adding a custom view that has the `backgroundColor` I want for my `navigationBar`. I then set *constraints* for the top to `view.topAnchor` and for the bottom to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`. This is the span between the very top of the screen and the top of the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`, which runs just underneath the `navigationBar`.

I am not entirely sure if this is the best possible solution, so please let me know if there is a better way and/or what issues I might face with this approach.